# What is the best partitioning and its sizes for SSD, to contain everything related to Mint 19.1

Tags: linux, windows-7, partitioning, ssd, linux-mint

++ For a Laptop, 300GB HDD, 3GB Ram, USB2, with Win7.
++ To install Linux Mint 19.1, with a dual boot with Win7.
++ In the case of installing Linux Mint 19.1, on a 120GB SSD, mounted in a Caddy DVD.
++ The question is:- 
What is the best partitioning and its sizes for this SSD, to contain everything related to Mint19.1 only?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single "best" practice, but there are considerations.

Partitions are often used to separate different parts or purposes of the installation, either to simplify maintenance or because some purposes have different requirements.  For example:

- Linux will work better if it has access to a swap partition, which doesn't use the same format as the operating system.
- Having the home directory tree (your files and configurations) in a separate partition from the root directory tree (the operating system) makes it easier to do a major upgrade or recovery of the OS without affecting your files.
- Backing up the system can be easier to do if the OS is in a separate partition from your files.
- If you keep big archives or libraries of files, it may be easier to maintain them if they are in their own partition.
- If you want to share files between Linux and Windows, you might want them stored in a different filesystem that both OSes can use well natively.
- If you use a utility like Timeshift to store snapshots of the system to aid in recovery, those utilities often want some form of "protection" for the contents.

How many partitions you use and why depends on how you will be using the system.

If you separate things into different partitions, you want to allow some free space in each partition for future needs.  You can't always predict how much space you'll eventually need for each purpose, so you can end up having inadequate space in one partition and unneeded space in another.  Partitions can be changed if there is still available space, but it isn't a trivial task.

If you have a small drive, dividing it into a lot of partitions for different purposes can be a problem if you don't guess the space needs right.  When different things share the same partition, you can have one pool of free space that gets used by whatever needs it.

This just scratches the surface, but you get the idea why there isn't a "best".  But here are a few considerations for your situation.

- A 120 GB drive is a good amount of space for a typical setup.  If you have huge libraries of images or media files, you might want to put that on another drive, though.
- You're adding a drive for Linux, and making it an SSD while you're at it.  But something just to think about: the SSD will have a big speed advantage.  Some things will benefit from that speed and some won't.  An OS will boot faster.  Software will load faster, and big software that loads what it needs when it needs it will run faster.  Database work will be faster.  Etc.  On the other hand, loading and editing a small office file, backing up in the background, and some other tasks, won't give you a performance advantage using an SSD for that.

  You could get more bang for your buck if you allocate things differently between the drives.  You may not want to mess with that now, but you could plan for it for when Win 7 is out of support.  Leave some free space on the SSD, and later, you can shuffle things around to take best advantage of the SSD.
- Use a swap partition, you have the space.  The optimum varies a little by how much memory you have.  A swap partition at least the size of your RAM allows you to hibernate the system.  The swap partition is used to augment RAM.  3 GB of RAM is pretty limited for typical usage.  The system could benefit from a swap partition of double that (6 GB).  If the system had a ton of RAM, just 1x or 1.5x might be adequate.
- Put root in a separate partition.  That will simplify backup, recovery, and major upgrades.  Mint is a fully-loaded OS.  It also comes with a fair amount of software.  If your software needs are pretty basic and you won't be adding much else, probably 15-20 GB would be adequate for a root partition.  If you use lots of different kinds of software, have your own software preferences or like to try different applications, maybe 30 GB would do it.  If you are a software hoarder and like to grab everything you see, or collect games and want them all on your computer, pick a number.
- Put home in a separate partition.  Even if your own needs are pretty minimal, that's where your email and browser profiles are stored, which contain all of your email messages if you use POP3, all of your browser-related storage, etc.  So you probably want at least 10-15 GB, but for modest amounts of mostly office suite documents, 30 GB.  It goes up from there if you are a heavy computer user and have a plentiful collection of files.  Media files will generally take more space than office suite documents.  Large collections of images can burn through storage space.  You can get a rough idea of how much space you'll need by looking at the user directories in Windows.

  If you add certain software packages manually because you need them and they aren't in the repository, some may get installed in home.  If you use Wine to run Windows software, or set up a virtual machine, those can suck up substantial chunks of additional space.  So how big to make a home partition is driven by how you will use the computer.
- There are other partitions you might want, depending on your needs.  Some Linux users put certain of the root directories in a separate partition, but that isn't something you would need to mess with as a new Linux user.  You might want a partition for system snapshots, although putting that on the SSD would be a waste of SSD resources.  You might want a partition to share files with Windows, although that probably wouldn't need to be a huge partition and could be stuck on the HDD.

  You might want to leave some free space for some future purpose.  There's a benefit to having that flexibility.  But don't shortchange known current requirements for potential future requirements.  It isn't trivial to modify partitions.  Leave adequate, reasonable space in the partitions you create for specific purposes, just be cognizant that if you arbitrarily dump in a big chunk of extra space that you may never use, that won't be available if you later identify some other purpose for which you want another partition.

Comment: .++ That is a great help. It is a push in the right direction. ++ I feel receiving a light in hand, and directions on the road. + I need now first studying carefully all these stations in the way. ++ It will take me time, but it deserves it. ++ Fortunately, there is an enough time to study every step, 5 months is a good chance for studying. ++ I would like to add one point, may be it helps a lot of people with me, as one of the win7 users who were desiring to continue with it, unless Microsoft killed it, we are all longing to have something very close to Win7, in every thing.(cont'd)

Comment: We have been forced to leave Win7, so we desire to find its twin!! It is the reality. +++ In this point of view, what could you please advice us all to do?. +++ I am appreciating your excellent help, and feel that you are the one who can and wants to guide us all in the right direction, instead of the loops that we are turning in it now. +++ Of course I'll need some further help about points of your detailed explanation, but I'll ask after studying it carefully. +++ Many thanks in advance

Comment: @MakramZakiShenouda, addressing "something very close to Windows 7" would require a long magazine article or short book.  Way beyond what could be done in comments.  :-)

Comment: +++Many thanks for your reply. ++ Yes, that is a wide question, without limits. ++ What was in my mind is: “very close” in the point of view of the usual, non-technical, users of windows 7. ++ Or as you have said before, those who do not have knowledge of how the OS works, but only know how to use it. ++ And I meant also “very close” in appearance and in using it, even if the things have different names, but the same action. +++ It is a very difficult thing to obtain. ++ So, it may be more logic to identify:- the most possible closer to Win7, in appearance and actions. (Con'd)

Comment: +++ Inspite of its difficulty, all the ordinary users of Win7 are searching day and night for it, especially for those who faced bad problems after using Win10. ++ We still have a hope that it will happen!! I hope so!!! +++ We appreciate very much any help leads us to reach that difficult aim. +++ Many thanks, with all respect

Comment: @MakramZakiShenouda, comment-sized response.  1. The Windows 7 total user experience is not mostly the user interface.  It's largely things you probably take for granted and don't think about, but that you would find different in unexpected ways going to Linux.  2. For a new, non-technical Linux user trying to replicate as much of the total experience as possible, Mint is probably the best compromise for a first distro.  As far as desktop environment, Xfce is very Win7-like and lightweight for an old computer with limited resources, and it's stable.  (cont'd)

Comment: Mate is similar, but I'd rank it lower.  Cinnamon is a little different but close enough, and a little heavier, but it would work fine in 3 GB RAM.  Those are the 3 available on Mint.  I'd download Xfce and Cinnamon and try both live sessions to see which you find preferable.  Play with the customizations.  3. Plan on using Linux software on Linux.  There are some packages that have become the defacto standards.  LibreOffice to replace MS Office and Thunderbird to replace Outlook.  Both are available in Windows versions and they're free.  (cont'd)

Comment: Don't wait until you switch to Linux to learn everything new from scratch all at once.  Install those packages on Win7 and start getting used to them while you're still on Windows.  If you already know your main applications, transitioning to Linux will be much less overwhelming.

Comment: ++ First, many thanks for the great continuous help. ++ About the previous explanations, and by saying “You could also reduce risks by disconnecting the Windows drive while you install Linux”, Do you mean please to disconnect the hardware itself physically?. ++ Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @MakramZakiShenouda, in a desktop computer, you could just disconnect the cable.  In laptops, there is often a connector mounted on the mainboard that works almost like a dock.  The drive slides into it and then is secured by a screw or two that are readily visible and accessible.  In that setup, you would remove any securing screws and pull out the drive.  When you're done, slide the drive back in and put the screws back.  The hard drive is usually under a removable cover on the case so you can get at it without needing to disassemble the laptop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the illustration. ++ About LibreOffice, I downloaded it just now, I found a lot of information that should be read first. ++ I am continuing reading your all replies. Is it better please to put separate new questions or continuing here (in fact, I prefer continuing here, but it is up to you). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @MakramZakiShenouda, we're pushing the boundaries here.  :-)  Anything that is an on-topic, in-scope question should really be a new actual question (and I'll suggest it). Comments are intended for clarification of the post, not open-ended discussion. If this thread gets too long, one of us may get a prompt asking to move it to a chat room.  If so, we should do it.  You don't have enough rep yet for a chat room, but if the system creates it, you'll have permissions in that room.  There, discussion is fine.  If a moderator sees this thread, they might move it to chat, which would work, also.

Comment: Thank you very much. ++ As you said: "Comments are intended for clarification of the post,", I will just ask for clarifications of the previous explanations. ++ If I have a new question, I will put it in a new Query. ++ In fact I will continue to study your previous explanations slowly, trying to understand it carefully before asking, to spare your time and effort. ++ Many thanks again